# Plot next image only after current window is closed

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, python-interactive

I have a bunch of satellite images that I am inspecting for errors and it is pretty tedious. I would like a way to do this efficiently in Python where I can look at an image, close the window when I'm done, look at the next image, etc. without requiring me to alter the code each time (e.g. `plt.imshow(image1)`, `plt.imshow(image2)`, etc.).

I tried using `input()` which pauses a function until the user presses ENTER but unfortunately it prevents `plt.imshow()` from displaying the image until the loop is completely finished, and then it only shows the last image in the loop.

```
npoints = 100 * 100
noise = randgen.randn(npoints).reshape([100, 100])
image_1 = np.mgrid[0:100:100j, 0:100:100j][0]
image_2 = np.mgrid[0:100:100j, 0:100:100j][1]
image_3 = image_1 * image_2
images = [image_1, image_2, image_3]

for image in images:
    plt.imshow(image)
    input()
```

Any ideas for how I might do this, or another way to interactively plot in Python?

Thank you

Comment: You could add a figure using `plt.figure()` and `plt.show()` in the end of the iteration.                  `for image in images: plt.figure(); plt.imshow();  plt.show()`. Furthermore you could also connect the canvas to an event that changes the image being displayed. See this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html

Comment: The `plt.show()` is the important part in @p479h comment. Matplotlib plots images when control of the command line is returned to the user -- unless forced by using `plt.show` or `fig.canvas.draw()`, etc

Comment: hmm @p479h thank you for your comment, that doesn't seem to work though. It plots all of the images at once. Unless I am doing it incorrectly, in which case maybe you could comment the full solution? I will look at matplotlib events though

Answer (score 0):

I looked deeper at event handling in matplotlib and found a suitable solution using `plt.waitforbuttonpress()`

```
npoints = 100 * 100
noise = randgen.randn(npoints).reshape([100, 100])
image_1 = np.mgrid[0:100:100j, 0:100:100j][0]
image_2 = np.mgrid[0:100:100j, 0:100:100j][1]
image_3 = image_1 * image_2
images = [image_1, image_2, image_3]

for image in images:
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
    plt.close()
```